# Convert nth character of all filenames in a directory to uppercase in bash

Tags: linux, bash

For files like :

`_aaa.txt`
`_bbb.txt`
`_ccc.txt`

I want to convert them to :

`_aAa.txt`
`_bBb.txt`

Any idea how to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In plain `bash`, using only shell parameter expansions to perform the conversion:

```
#!/bin/bash

n=3
for file in *; do
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    suffix=${file:n-1}
    mv -i "$file" "${file:0:n-1}${suffix^}"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the output of the following

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for filename in *; do    
newname=$(sed 's/./\U&/3' <<< "$filename")
echo "$filename --> $newname"
# mv $filename $newname
done
```

Then remove the `#`, if the filename printed is correct

Answer (score 0):

If `rename` command is available, please try:

```
rename 's/^(..)(.)/$1\U$2/' *.txt
```

Comment: Bare in mind that there's more than one tool by that name out and about, and not all use the same syntax ..